# UIImageView added to cell contentView displaying randomly when scrolling through UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c

My `UITableView` is pulling data from an array. Items in this array have a property called IsSelected.  I am trying to put a `UIImageView` in the cell `contentView` for each item that is selected.

The `UITableView` however when reusing the cell is causing my image to be reused on cells that it shouldn't.  I cannot figure out for the life of me how I should be doing it differently. I have attached a screen shot showing the issue. If I keep scrolling up and down the image goes all over the place:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *SchoolCellIdentifer = @"SchoolCellIdentifier";

    SchoolInfoItem *item = [self.schoolsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SchoolCellIdentifer];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SchoolCellIdentifer];
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [BVColors WebDarkBlue];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = item.Name;

    if ([item.selected isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [BVColors WebBlue];
        UIImageView *selectedItemCheckMarkIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300, 13, 17, 17.5)];
        [selectedItemCheckMarkIcon setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check-mark.png"]];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:selectedItemCheckMarkIcon];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [BVColors WebDarkBlue];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the `UIImageView` is getting removed from the cell content view. It looks like in your code when a cell gets dequeued that imageview is still in the cells view hierarchy.

Best solution is to have your cell hold onto a reference to the image view and remove it when necessary.

Take the following:

```
if ([item.selected isEqualToString:@"1"])
{
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [BVColors WebBlue];
    cell.myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300, 13, 17, 17.5)];
    [selectedItemCheckMarkIcon setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check-mark.png"]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.myImageView];
}
else
{
    [cell.myImageView removeFromSuperview];
    cell.myImageView = nil;
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [BVColors WebDarkBlue];
}
```

Note in the else case the removal of the imageview.

Answer (score 1):

You keep adding a the UIImageView as a subview on the cell's contentView. This isn't removed when the table view is reusing the cell. You'll need to remove the subview if it shouldn't appear.

You should make `selectedItemCheckMarkIcon` a property on your `UITableViewCell` subclass. And then have a method in your subclass where you set the image or visibility of the image accordingly.

You could also use the `accessoryView` property on the UITableView and set the imageView as that:

```
if ([item.selected isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [BVColors WebBlue];
    UIImageView *selectedItemCheckMarkIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check-mark.png"]];
    cell.accessoryView = selectedItemCheckMarkIcon;
} else {
    cell.accessoryView = nil;
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [BVColors WebDarkBlue];
}
```

Note that you don't need to set a frame in this case because the system will automatically set the frame correctly for the `accessoryView`.

Comment: Thanks runmad! I appreciate your feedback. I marked Dan's as the answer because he replied first but I marked yours as helpful! Thanks again!

Comment: No worries. I do recommend that you use `accessoryView` though, since it makes it easier to manage if all you need is a checkmark :) Comes with proper framing and is easy to remove for cell where you don't need it.